# append the multiple selected items from datalist to input tag with comma

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select, html-datalist

when I select an item from datalist tag the text should we have written in the req-skills input tag, and then I select again the selected item should appear in a req-skills input tag with the previous one selected and separated by " , "

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#input-skill').click(function() {

        var txt = "";
        $('input-skill:selected').each(function() {
            txt+=$(this).val() + " , "
        });
        txt = txt.substring(0,txt.length-1);
        $('#req-skill').val(txt);
        $('#req-skill').innerHTML = txt ;

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="req-skill" placeholder="Skills">
  <input type="text" list="skills" name="input-skill" id="input-skill"  placeholder="Select skills here" size="50" multiple>
  <datalist id="skills">
      <option value="website">
      <option value="django">
      <option value="javascript">
      <option value="app-development">
      <option value="software designer">
      <option value="python developer">
  </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not use a `<select>` then `<option>` ?

Comment: ok after using select how to select multiple and append in the input tag